# How to set paddingTop for text in AppCompatCheckBox

Tags: android

I using `AppCompatCheckBox` and I get one problem:

[image]
I want lower text in `AppCompatCheckBox` below red line.

How can I set `paddingTop` for Text in `AppCompatCheckBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give it a top padding like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="your text here"/>
```

Works for me. Attaching screenshot [image]